# Dgrid sorted but not sorted in the store?

Tags: sorting, dgrid

when I sort the dgrid, clicking on some column header, the view of the grid changes. When for example I call "getSelectedRows" on the grid object, I get the list of selected rows but not sorted.
I need to get on the js, the list of sorted rows because I must print them in a pdf in the same sorting that the grid views the results.
Is there in dgrid a function, an object or something else to permit me to get this result?
Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which version of dgrid you are using, if you are using dgrid 0.3 you can get rendered data of grid like this from it's store

```
var sortedData=grid.store.query(grid.get('query'),{sort:grid.get('sort')});
```

in dgrid 0.4 you can just use_renderedCollection property of dgrid